# Codeception Phpunit getMockBuilder ошибка

Tags: phpunit, codeception

При запуске Юнит тестов через `Codeception`, если в тесте используется метод `getMockBuilder`, то вылетает фатальная ошибка:

> With stubPHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&'
>   or variable (T_VARIABLE) in
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/codecept/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Builder/InvocationMocker.php
>   on line 93

Тест в котором используется `getMockBuilder`

```
public function testWithStub()
{
    // Create a stub for the Calculator class.
    $calculator = $this->getMockBuilder('Calculator')
        ->getMock();

    // Configure the stub.
    $calculator->expects($this->any())
        ->method('add')
        ->willReturn(6);

    $this->assertEquals(6, $calculator->add(0,0));
}
```

Запуск теста напрямую через `PhpUnit` дает положительный результат.

Насколько я понимаю, `Codeception` использует свою версию `PhpUnit`, может быть в этом дело?

Помогите решить проблему, или укажите куда копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том что на сервере установлена версия php 5.5 c php 5.6 все работает отлично.